# Function for shuffling cards

Tags: python, python-3.x, playing-cards

Assignment from [here](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61a/fa12/hw/hw4.html)

> Q6. Define a function shuffle that takes a list with an even number of elements (cards) and creates a new list that interleaves the elements of the first half with the elements of the second half:

```
def card(n):
    """Return the playing card type for a positive n <= 13."""
    assert type(n) == int and n > 0 and n <= 13, "Bad card n"
    specials = {1: 'A', 11: 'J', 12: 'Q', 13: 'K'}
    return specials.get(n, str(n))

def shuffle(cards):
    """Return a shuffled list that interleaves the two halves of cards.

    >>> suits = ['♡', '♢', '♤', '♧']
    >>> cards = [card(n) + suit for n in range(1,14) for suit in suits]
    >>> cards[:12]
    ['A♡', 'A♢', 'A♤', 'A♧', '2♡', '2♢', '2♤', '2♧', '3♡', '3♢', '3♤', '3♧']
    >>> cards[26:30]
    ['7♤', '7♧', '8♡', '8♢']
    >>> shuffle(cards)[:12]
    ['A♡', '7♤', 'A♢', '7♧', 'A♤', '8♡', 'A♧', '8♢', '2♡', '8♤', '2♢', '8♧']
    >>> shuffle(shuffle(cards))[:12]
    ['A♡', '4♢', '7♤', '10♧', 'A♢', '4♤', '7♧', 'J♡', 'A♤', '4♧', '8♡', 'J♢']
    >>> cards[:12]  # Should not be changed
    ['A♡', 'A♢', 'A♤', 'A♧', '2♡', '2♢', '2♤', '2♧', '3♡', '3♢', '3♤', '3♧']
    >>> repeated(shuffle, 8)(cards) == cards
    True
    """
    assert len(cards) % 2 == 0, 'len(cards) must be even'
    "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"
```

Solution:

```
def card(n):
    """Return the playing card type for a positive n <= 13."""
    assert type(n) == int and n > 0 and n <= 13, "Bad card n"
    specials = {1: 'A', 11: 'J', 12: 'Q', 13: 'K'}
    return specials.get(n, str(n))

def shuffle(cards, index = 1, incr = 0):
    """Return a shuffled list that interleaves the two halves of cards.

    >>> suits = ['♡', '♢', '♤', '♧']
    >>> cards = [card(n) + suit for n in range(1,14) for suit in suits]
    >>> cards[:12]
    ['A♡', 'A♢', 'A♤', 'A♧', '2♡', '2♢', '2♤', '2♧', '3♡', '3♢', '3♤', '3♧']
    >>> cards[26:30]
    ['7♤', '7♧', '8♡', '8♢']
    >>> shuffle(cards)[:12]
    ['A♡', '7♤', 'A♢', '7♧', 'A♤', '8♡', 'A♧', '8♢', '2♡', '8♤', '2♢', '8♧']
    """
    assert len(cards) % 2 == 0, 'len(cards) must be even'
    if index > (len(cards) // 2):
        element = cards.pop((len(cards) // 2) + incr)
        cards.insert(index, element)
        return cards
    else:
        element = cards.pop((len(cards) // 2) + incr)
        cards.insert(index, element)
        return shuffle(cards, index + 2, incr + 1)
```

Can I improve this solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are not supposed to modify the list in-place. Instead, return a shuffled copy of the original list. This is also checked by this doc test:

```
>>> cards[:12]  # Should not be changed
['A♡', 'A♢', 'A♤', 'A♧', '2♡', '2♢', '2♤', '2♧', '3♡', '3♢', '3♤', '3♧']
```

Furthermore, using recursion makes this overly complicated. After all, the solution to get the desired result is pretty simple: Cut the list in half and then take one item alternatively from each sublist. The first part is simple splicing, and ways to do the latter is covered [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678869/pythonic-way-to-combine-two-lists-in-an-alternating-fashion). So you could end up with this:

```
def shuffle (cards):
    # split the list in halves
    first, second = cards[:len(cards) // 2], cards[len(cards) // 2:]

    # combine them alternatively, e.g.
    return sum(map(list, zip(first, second)), [])
```

You can also do it without splitting the list by just iterating it alternatively from the beginning and from the middle:

```
def shuffle (cards):
    result = []
    half = len(cards) // 2
    for i in range(half):
        result.append(cards[i])
        result.append(cards[i + half])
    return result
```